# Extract elements from lfile into a list in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a file such as :

```
>Nscaffold_033778.1_22 [24674 - 24880] some information  
ACCATTAAGAGAGAAAAGAGAGGAGAGAGAGAGAGGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGGagAGGAAGA
AGGAGAGAGA
>NC_0337652.1_23 [26291 - 26443] some other informations boring
MMDOODODODODNJBCIOICICVOCICVCPCCM
>contig_033652.1_24 [25507 - 26529] species with informations 
AJGSIVPDYVPDYVDPYVDPYDVDYVPVYVIYVDPIDVYPDIVYDPIYVDPIDVYPDIVP
PUDVPIYDVPDIVPDIDVPDVPDIVDPVDIVPDIVPDIVDPIDVIDVPDDIVPDDVPDVD
DDGGDDGDDIDIDDFDUDUDTTUDDUCDUDCDCC
```

And I would like to extract in a list format only the following informations :

the list:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Nscaffold_033778.1_22" "24674"        "24880"       

[[2]]
[1] "NC_0337652.1_23" "26291"        "26443"       

[[3]]
[1] "contig_033652.1_24" "25507"         "26529"
```

Does someone have an idea ??

- The first element of the list is the part after the `">"` symbols,
- The second element of the list is the `first number` within the `[]`
- The third element of the list is the `second number` within the `[]`

Comment: What is the file/data format?

Comment: What was your idea you tried but didn't work ?

Answer (score 3):

If `vec` holds the file contents,

```r
vec <- readLines(...)
```

then

```r
strcapture("^>(.*) *\\[(\\d+)\\D*(\\d+).*",
           vec[grepl("^>", vec)],
           list(x="",y="",z=""))
#                        x     y     z
# 1 Nscaffold_033778.1_22  24674 24880
# 2       NC_0337652.1_23  26291 26443
# 3    contig_033652.1_24  25507 26529
```

I recognize this is not strictly the format requested. I offer it as an alternate, as it gives ready access to all of the contents. Further, if you intend to integer-ize the columns `y` and `z`, then you can do that built-in by replacing the third argument (`proto=`) with `list(x="", y=1L, z=1L)`, as in

```r
str(
  strcapture("^>(.*) *\\[(\\d+)\\D*(\\d+).*",
             vec[grepl("^>", vec)],
             list(x="",y="",z=""))
)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ x: chr  "Nscaffold_033778.1_22 " "NC_0337652.1_23 " "contig_033652.1_24 "
#  $ y: chr  "24674" "26291" "25507"
#  $ z: chr  "24880" "26443" "26529"

str(
  strcapture("^>(.*) *\\[(\\d+)\\D*(\\d+).*",
             vec[grepl("^>", vec)],
             list(x="",y=1L,z=1L))
)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ x: chr  "Nscaffold_033778.1_22 " "NC_0337652.1_23 " "contig_033652.1_24 "
#  $ y: int  24674 26291 25507
#  $ z: int  24880 26443 26529
```

Answer (score 2):

We could read the file with `readLines`, `grep` the lines, extract the relevant info and split

```
strsplit(sub("^>(\\S+)\\s+\\[(\\d+)\\D+(\\d+)\\].*", "\\1,\\2,\\3", 
    grep(">", lines, value = TRUE)), ",")
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] "Nscaffold_033778.1_22" "24674"                 "24880"                

[[2]]
[1] "NC_0337652.1_23" "26291"           "26443"          

[[3]]
[1] "contig_033652.1_24" "25507"              "26529"
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines('file.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use {unglue}  :

```r
data <- c(">Nscaffold_033778.1_22 [24674 - 24880] some information",
  ">NC_0337652.1_23 [26291 - 26443] some other information",
  ">contig_033652.1_24 [25507 - 26529] species with informations")

unglue::unglue_data(data, ">{id} [{n1} - {n2}]{}")
#>                      id    n1    n2
#> 1 Nscaffold_033778.1_22 24674 24880
#> 2       NC_0337652.1_23 26291 26443
#> 3    contig_033652.1_24 25507 26529
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>